# How to change the width of input field

Tags: html, css

I'm new to html & css and I'm trying to change the width of my name input but it doesn't change no matter what the value I put. What's the problem and how do I fix it?

Here's my HTML code:

```
   <div class="form-container">
        <form>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="next-to-each">
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
                    <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

I tried changing the values of the width but it doesn't affect the input. The solution I found is setting the margin right to negative but it seems not right and I wanna know why I cant change the width

Here's my CSS Code:

```
#name {
    width: 70%;
  }

.next-to-each{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.next-to-each input{
    margin-left: 10px;
    flex: 1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the width effect on the `input` you have to remove the CSS : `flex:1`

`Flex:1` means the horizontal space will be automatically filled, so clearly no effect of width will be seen.

```css
.next-to-each{
    display: flex;
}

.next-to-each input{
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 10%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="form-container">
        <form>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="next-to-each">
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
                    <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```